# win2003-server How to add CNAME to DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

To the existing DNS I will need to add a CNAME. So that a web server in one country can be easily moved to another country. I'm using 2003 server

I will need to add the following:

- domain: origin.mycompany.eu
- currentname 212.90.x.x
- newname: CNAME origin.advantech.com

I went to the Primary DNS server.
I went to Mycompany.eu
I've pressed new CNAME
I've added the information above.

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats pretty much it. There isn't much to adding records in Server 2003, just make sure you are adding it to your proper forward lookup zone.